# FBO and VBO for performance

Tags: opengl, java, rendering, lwjgl, vbo

I discovered VBO's recently and changed my code to use them instead of immediate mode. Now I'm rendering 25000 squares and it's really slowing down my FPS.  If I drew all the squares VBO's to an FBO,  then bound it to a single VBO, would it increases performance?
The 25000 squares is more of a stress test,  im trying to optimize my rendering code for snow. 
Edit : Each snow particle draws one of three static VBO's,  this helped performance.

Comment: You can't bind a VBO to an FBO. For snow, use instancing.

Comment: compare with how many square you could have drawn without VBOs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have only 1 VBO that contains all of your squares and render it in one single draw call.

Use a texture atlas to combine all your snowflake textures.

Also, look into using a geometry shader to do point sprite expansion, this can reduce your VBO to a single vec4 encoding it as (position.x, position.y, position.z, angle).
Have the geometry shader generate the UVs and vertex coordinates from that point+angle.